# sqlcl vs sqlplus pl/sql compatability

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sqlcl

I apologize up-front for this super-lightweight question, but I'm missing something when starting to work with sqlcl as a potential replacement for sqlplus.

sqlcl is compelling, but I'm troubled in that I'm missing how to run anonymous-blocks interactively.  The below example works fine when saved as Little-Anonymous-Block.sql and run in sqlcl via @Little-Anonymous-Block.sql, but the raw pl/sql fails with the the below PLS-00103.

Little-Anonymous-Block.sql:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This anonymous-block ran in sqlcl!');
END;
/
```

Running as a Script:

> SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
>
> SQL> @Little-Anonymous-Block.sql;
>
> This anonymous-block ran in sqlcl!
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

But running ad-hoc:

> SQL> BEGIN
>
> 2    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This anonymous-block ran in sqlcl!');
>
> 3  END;
>
> 4  /

gives:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>
> BEGIN
>
> DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This anonymous-block ran in sqlcl!');
>
> END;/
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.

sqlcl appears to be conjoining the "/" with the block-terminating END;
The same command works fine in sqlplus.

Can you tell me, how do I interactively run anonymous blocks in sqlcl?  I've got the early-adopter release from 20160513. java 8.0_77.  Apologies for this question if its in the sqlcl manual, I didn't find much to go by on the oracle [sqlcl-page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html).

Comment: Certainly, if you remove the `/`, it will then execute the annonymous block in sqlcl. Also, if you enter `show all`, you should see the `SQL*Plus mode off`. I suspect if you turn that on, you should get the behavior you are used to.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickBacon about SQL\*Plus mode.  I'll run with that.  However, removing the terminator does not get anon blocks to execute.  sqlcl does not detect the block end (behavior much like SQL\*Plus).  Any thoughts on that?  Is there a good sqlcl doc anywhere?  "HELP /" doesn't have much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that you can run an anonymous block with `exec` but that has its limitations (e.g. all code on one line).
[image: SQLcl session]

As far as I can tell what you've found is a bug.  A workaround would be to end your block with a `.` then execute the buffer with a `/` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Ok, bugs happen.  I'll look into whether it's been filed over on oracle.  This workaround is acceptable meantime. Thanks for taking a look.  I'll accept.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

This was indeed a bug.  It should be fixed in the latest release on OTN

```
BARRY@orcl☘ >BEGIN
  2  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This anonymous-block ran in sqlcl!');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

BARRY@orcl☘ >l
  1  BEGIN
  2  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This anonymous-block ran in sqlcl!');
  3* END;
BARRY@orcl☘ >
```